# Grouping Rows by variables in KableExtra

Tags: kableextra, gt

this is my first question here so I am uncertain on how to word things. However, I am looking into the kableExtra package for creating different tables than the ones I currently know in gt. This is my table output from gt.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI264.jpg)

Now what I am trying to do is group my kable table in a similar way to this. This data set is exactly what you see, with the addition of a column I have named "x" that includes Prevalence, Abundance, and Intensity for each different row. Is there a way to have a similar output for a kable table? The difficulty that I am having is because this table in gt is so lengthy it doesn't fit very well in a document. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.